# Dropdown change event not working for one option in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I am dynamically adding a select tag ,and appending option from the data comming from server and on change of the dropdown i have to put the selected data in textbox,

But if there is only one option onchange event will not work what should i do please help

My problem will be more clear by below example

```
var dynamicHtmlDisplay = "<input type=\"button\" Value=\"" + strAf_Manual + "\" class=\"btnAddManual\" /> </br>"

    dynamicHtmlDisplay += "<select class=\"Test form-control\"><option>--</option></select>"
```

And after a server call i am fillin the dropdown

```
 $('.Test').empty();
    $.each(Result, function (i, p) {
        $('.Test').append($('<option></option>').val(JSON.stringify(p)).html(p.Text));
    });
```

And on change event i am entering the selected text in an textbox

```
 $(".Test").change(function () {
        var selectedObject = JSON.parse($('option:selected', this).val())
});
```

But if only one value is there in `dropdown` my change does not work is there anything else instead of `onchange` event ,Something like `onselect` event.

Comment: How about you add one option with no value "Select an option". This will improve the usability also

Comment: If it isn't too late in the process, maybe you can bind to `blur` instead of `change`.  This will fire when the user leaves that field, regardless of if they changed their selection or number of options.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from the documentation for https://api.jquery.com/change/

It only works when you change the value of the dropdown, is there is only one value you didn't "change" it.

A solution is to add a blank value which is deleted after your first change call

`<option value="0"></option>
 <option value="1">First option</option>`

`$("#select1").change(function(){
    // You delete the blank value for the first call
    $("#select1 option[value=0]").remove();
    ...`

Comment: You don't have to do this as object is getting generated after change event is bind to select control. The select control is getting generated dynamically and there is no binding for the control.

Comment: Then you just need to add a blank value before calling .each

Answer (score 0):

Parshuram,
I assume that you are going to load select control using code behind and the below code would still work if you maintain classes and on function.

I hope this will help you. All you need is on function. Enjoy!

```js
$(function(){
var Result = [{id:'1', value:'One'},{id:'2',value:'Two'}];
$('.Test').empty();
    $.each(Result, function (i, p) {
        $('.Test').append($('<option></option>').val(p.id).html(p.value));
    });
    
    $('.form-wrapper').on('change','.Test',function(){
      console.log('You have selected: ' + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-wrapper">
<input type="button" Value="Add Option" class="btnAddManual" /> </br>
<select class="Test form-control"><option>--</option></select>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't see alert on selection change? I do get alert. I am just trying to feed you basic code and then you can take it from there.
Also, I change alert to console log. Good luck bro!

Comment: If there is only one value in dropdown then what should i do

Comment: Usually first option is "Select", why you would use dropdown for only one option.

Comment: i want to tell user which option is selected by an alert

Answer (score 0):

Normally Dropdown change event will not fire if you select the same dropdown option.So it will not work for a single value.